# Help please with finding the equation and pattern of Taylor Series. (2 problems I have attempted down below).

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I didn't want to ask twice so I combined both of my questions together. I have just started on Taylor Series, and I'm not very good at figuring out patterns.

**First Question**

Find Taylor Series for $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{(9-x)^9}$ at x=8.

So here is the work I have done so far:

[image]

I am not sure how to write the rest of the "pattern". I notice that 9 x 10 = 90 and 90 x 11 = 990.

**Second Question**

Find Taylor Series for $\displaystyle f(x)=\sqrt{x+36}$ at x=0. Write the answer in the form $\displaystyle a+b x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty c_n x^n$ where $a,bx$ and each $c_n$ are constants.

So here is the work I did so far:

[image]

Not sure what to write in the (?). I cannot find a pattern at all in this.

Comment: For the first function, try finding $f^n(x)$ generally. Notice repeated power rule gives you a 'partial' factorial. I got something like $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(n+8)!}{8!} (9-x)^{-(n+9)}$

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try that, but what does it mean to find it generally

Comment: In general, the pattern might be easier to discern if you don't expand products, for instance leaving $\frac{3}{62208}$ as $\frac{3}{2^3  6^5}$.

Comment: To help find the pattern, try writing the derivatives in unsimplified form.  For the first example, you have $f^{(3)}(x)=9\cdot10\cdot11(9-x)^{-12}$ and $f^{(4)}(x)=9\cdot10\cdot11\cdot12(9-x)^{-13}$, for instance.  In the second example, $f^{(3)}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{3}{2})(x+36)^{-5/2}$ and $f^{(4)}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{3}{2})(-\frac{5}{2})(x+36)^{-7/2}$, for instance.

Comment: Find the $n$th derivative for any $x$. Then plug in $x=8$ to find $f^{(n)}(8)$ which is useful since the Taylor series for $f$ is given by $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(8)}{n!} (x-8)^{n}$

Comment: Both of these series are examples of Binomial series; see, for example, http://statland.org/binomial.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For the first function the series is
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(n+8)!}{8!(n!)}(x-8)^n$$

For the second 
$$y=6+x/12+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!!}{2^n6^{2n-1}(n!)}x^n$$

Comment: why did u put two !!?

Comment: I understand the first function, but I do not understand how u did the second one after the summation sign

Comment: @Elsa $$y''=-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{(x+36)^3}}=-\frac{1!!}{2^2*6^3}$$ , $$y'''=\frac{3}{8\sqrt{(x+36)^5}}=\frac{3!!}{2^3*6^5}$$ , $$y''''=-\frac{15}{16\sqrt{(x+36)^7}}=-\frac{5!!}{2^4*6^7}$$

Comment: oh!!!!!! i see the denominator pattern! ok ok! but what is the concept of the double !!? when i input this into my hw, it displayes (n-1)!! as ((n-1)!)!)

Comment: @Elsa $$5!!=5*3*1$$ , $$7!!=7*5*3*1$$  and so on. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Comment: oh thank u for telling me that! i didn't know that existed! my hw will not display (n-1)!! like that. is there any other way i can write this concept?

Comment: @Elsa Good luck and you are welcome